# TypeScript: OnExit decorator

Tags: typescript

Intro:

I have the following structure:
`Item` object that contains array of `Group(s)` and every group contains array of `User(s)`.
`Item` has the following API:
`addUser`, `removeUser`, `addGroup`, `removeGroup`, `addUnit` and `removeUnit`.
Each of those action triggers a new calculation of the `rank` property of each user (for a certain group).

I am looking for a way that in the end of each of API's actions the method `calcRank` will be triggered without calling it explicitly (something like OnExit decorator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The Advice Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(programming)) is really easy in a language as dynamic as JavaScript:

```
function before(behavior) {
  return method => function beforeHandler(...args) {
    behavior.apply(this, args);
    return method.apply(this, args);
  };
}

function after(behavior) {
  return method => function afterHandler(...args) {
    const result = method.apply(this, args);
    behavior.apply(this, [args, result]);
    return result;
  };
}

const id = _ => _;

function withAdvice({before: beforeBehavior = id, after: afterBehavior = id, skip: [] }) {
  return Class => Object.keys(Class.prototype).forEach(methodName => {
    if (!skip.contains(methodName)) {
      const method = Class.prototype[methodName];
      const afterDecorator = after(afterBehavior);
      const beforeDecorator = before(beforeBehavior);
      Class.prototype[methodName] = afterDecorator(beforeDecorator(method));
    }
  });
}


@withAdvice({
  after() {
    this.calcRank();
  },
  skip: ['calcRank']
})
class Item {
  addUser() {}
  removeUser() {}
  addGroup() {}
  removeGroup() {}
  addUnit() {}
  removeUnit() {}
  calcRank() {}
}
```

Comment: Looks awesome! When I go and try it with `TypeScript` does the setup would be different? and can you please explain this line: `const id = _ => _;` Thanks.